# Connecting WIFI Module to RJ45 pins output of device

Tags: connector, wifi, rj45

Extreme noob questions here.  I have a Lantronix XPico 240 wifi module that I need to connect to the rj45 output pins of a device the device pins are clearly marked but I am not sure about which pins to connect to on the WIFI module.

Pictures are below. I'm sthinking it is the RMII pins at the bottom of the module but I want to make sure.  If so, what does RMII stand for?

Bonus question - what type of connector is in the first pic I want to use this type of connector to connect the WIFI.  Like I said...noob questions.

Here is the device:

[image]

And here is a diagram of the wifi module:
[image]

Comment: https://docs.lantronix.com/products/xpico-200/ig/functionaldescr/#ethernet-interface

Comment: So, no direct connections. Get a PHY.

Comment: Looks like a JST connector.  http://www.jst.com/